# Why strict exogeneity implies that the regressor is uncorrelated with the error term?

Tags: least-squares, assumptions

One of the assumptions of the [classical linear regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Classical_linear_regression_model) is *strict exogeneity*, that is:

$ E[\epsilon | X ] = 0 $

This should [imply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Classical_linear_regression_model) that the regressors are uncorrelated with the errors:

$E[X^T \epsilon] = 0$

But why is this the case? How it can be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation),
$$
E[X^T \epsilon]=E[X^TE[\epsilon | X ]]=E[X^T0]=E[0]=0.
$$

Comment: I found this law [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation). In order for me to understand, would be correct to write $E[X^T \epsilon] = X^T E[\epsilon]$ since $X^T$ is given?

Comment: Because Wikipedia says $E(\epsilon) = E(E(\epsilon|X))$, not $E(X^T \epsilon) = E(X^T E(\epsilon|X))$

Comment: This would only be correct if $X$ were, as it is sometimes assumed, nonstochastic. The above derivation covers the (as many would say, more realistic) case in which the regressors are also treated as random variables.

Comment: Hack: So how this equation follows from what is written in Wikipedia? Wikipedia say $E(\epsilon) = E(E(\epsilon|X))$, you say $E(X^T \epsilon) = E(X^T E(\epsilon|X))$. You have one $X^T$ more inside the parenthesis

Comment: That's because if $X$ is fixed (a constant) it cannot possibly correlate with the error term, so that it is enough to consider if $E(\epsilon)=0$.

Comment: I still don't get the first equation but okay. Thanks